# trying to run parallel testcases in multiple browsers with selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to run two testcases with multiple browsers

My XML

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                  <suite name="Same TestCases on on same machine on different Browser"  verbose="3"  parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
                  <test name="Run on Firefox">
                  <parameter name="browser"  value="*chrome"/>
                  <classes>
                  <class name="SeleniumGrid"/>
                  </classes>
                  </test>

                  <test name="Run on IE">
                  <parameter name="browser"  value="*iexplore"/>
                  <classes>
                  <class name="SeleniumGrid"/>
                  </classes>
                  </test>
                  </suite>
```

CLASS

```
                   public class SeleniumGrid {

public Selenium selenium;
@Parameters( { "browser" })
@BeforeClass
public void setup(String browser) {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, browser,"http://google.com");
    selenium.start();
    test_first();
    test_second();
}
@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    selenium.stop();
}
@Test
public void test_first() {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("q", "First");
    selenium.click("btnG");
}
@Test
public void test_second() {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("q", "second");
    selenium.click("btnG");
}
```

}

It runs without error and opens 1 iexplorer and 1 firefox browser

my GRID Hub SnapSot showing  ACTIVE REMOTE CONTROLS :  chorome  &  Internet explorer

but browser are just empty pages ,where I was expecting google.com page .

Any idea where i am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selenium.open("http://google.com");
```

If it does not work try:

```
selenium.open("http://google.com");
selenium.open("http://google.com");
```

helped me with selenium in Opera.

If nothing works upgrade to WebDriver. Simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't using anything to do your forking.  What I do is create 2 test classes with 1 @Test in each one.  then, I use Gradle-maxParallelForks  or Maven Surefire-threads  to fork test-runner processes.  Also, TestNG can fork processes within one jvm and that works also as long as you set it to 'fork by classes".